# How to enable spectator mode in a remote "nohup running" server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, hosting

We have a mono minecraft server running with the nohup command on Linux, we are using putty to execute commands on the server, but the only way that I could figure out is to kill the Minecraft server process and then execute it normal (java `-jar`) and execute the allow cheats command maybe `/op user` and finish the process again, then run the server *again* in nohup.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Server Properties (server.properties) and Find game mode and make it 4
and select force game mode true

Comment: GM4? What's that?